# How to get the error of bat value in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

I'm trying to get the value of bat output, when an error occurs. but it seems to like the error won't return as string. here is the code:

```
stage("test111"){
  dir("${base_dir}\\server-frame-auth"){
          withMaven(jdk: 'jdk1.8', maven: 'M3') {
              try{
                result = bat (encoding: 'UTF-8', label: '', returnStdout: true, script: 'mvn clean deploy -DskipTests=true')
              } catch (ex){
                mail bcc: '', body: result, cc: '', from: 'xxx', replyTo: '', subject: "deploy failed!", to: 'xxx'
              }
         } 
  }
```

}

the result variable will not set, if bat command has error

Comment: Currently there is no option to use both `returnStdout` and `returnStdout` in the `bat` step. There is an open request for it, which includes some workarounds to get what you want: [JENKINS-44930](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-44930)

Comment: Why not just follow the [standard maven pipeline format](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/07/declarative-maven-project/#running-a-maven-build), but with bat in place of sh and catch in the [post failure](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post) section.

Comment: i'm trying to gather the error message  when deploying error occurs, and send the message as email to someone